# Angular.js: how to test both directive parser and formatter?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have implemented a simple directive to check username (it should match a regexp, and some more constraint; on blur it's capitalized).
This is my current implementation:

```
app.directive('checkUserName', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
      value: '=ngModel'
    },
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, model) {
      var USERNAME_REGEXP = /^[^_.$\[\]#\/][^.$\[\]#\/]*$/;
      model.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
        var user;
        var retval;
        if (!viewValue) {
          model.$setValidity('required', false);
          retval = null;
        }
        if (USERNAME_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {
          if (!user) {
            model.$setValidity('taken', true);
            model.$setValidity('invalid', true);
            retval = viewValue;
          } else {
            model.$setValidity('taken', false);
            model.$setValidity('invalid', true);
          }
        } else {
          model.$setValidity('taken', true);
          model.$setValidity('invalid', viewValue === '');
          retval = viewValue;
        }
        return retval;
      });
      model.$formatters.push(function(modelValue) {
        if (modelValue) {
          modelValue = capitalize(modelValue);
        }
        return modelValue;
      });
    }
  };
});

app.directive('renderOn', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      var event = attrs.renderOn;
      elm.bind(event, function() {
        var viewValue = ctrl.$modelValue;
        for (var i in ctrl.$formatters) {
          viewValue = ctrl.$formatters[i](viewValue);
        }
        ctrl.$viewValue = viewValue;
        ctrl.$render();
      });
    }
  };  
});

function capitalize(text) {
  return text.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + text.slice(1);
}
```

So the question is:
*How do I test it?*
I did set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54hvjbvv/1/) with the karma test I did write, but the blur handling is obviously wrong...

A secondary question is: *is this 'split' implementation (checkUserName + renderOn) advisable  strategy when implementing both 'parsing' and 'formatting' directives?*